# Implementing application security - App Level & DB level (ASP .NET & SQL Server 08)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, security

I am about to deploy an ASP .NET application (developed with LINQ-to-SQL).

I have taken following precautions:

- Database access via user with limited access, however, since application is to access the sensitive data, I can't deprive this limited access user from it
- Database server is not exposed to external network - is hiding behind DMZ and all external ports are blocked
- I have done thorough security testing of the web-application; SQL Injections, rights management, illegal data access (via post/get data tempering)
- Application is operating on SSL

Questions:

1 - I am using ASP .NET authorization API; any recommendation for avoiding session hijacking (in case someone some-how gets to know the session key). Is there are way to change the authentication cookie less prone to threats? Say like, changing it after every request? (I know I am get very conscious about this particular item)

2 - Data in the database is not encrypted. To make things ultra-secure, I am thinking about implementing transparent data encryption. Can someone share his/her experience or a link about implementing data level encryption with SQL Server 2008 along with pros-and-cons?

3 - Recommendation for storing connection string in web.config. Is using integrated security better then using encrypted database connection string?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's seems to me that it's enough of standard asp.net api for this task. There is a [very good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx) from MS P&P team about securing your forms authentication, it should help you.
2. I don't have such experience but here is a [link with article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx).
3. I don't know :(
   Also I recommend to check [AntiXSS](http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS) tool, it can show you some potential xss holes. And one last note, **never trust to user input**.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated security is your strongest option.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not an ASP.Net expert, but in my PHP projects I encrypt the cookie and affinitize it to a specific client IP. This way sessions cannot migrate to a different client. Ultimately, if you want to be absolutely sure, cannot rely on cookies for authentication, but instead use HTTP Digest, since browsers will transparently re-authenticate every request within the realm. Unfortunately this option does not work with the built-in ASP.Net membership providers as the HTTP Digest option they offer is half-brained to say the least (only authenticate against AD).
2. What specific threat are you trying to mitigate by encrypting data? TDE is designed to mitigate the threat of accidental media loss (ie. someone find an old disk of your with all the data on it, or you loose a laptop with the database on it). This is also the threat mitigate by *most* other database encryption schemes, like column encryption or file level encryption (bit locker). Other threats, like accidental compromise of *access* to the database (ie. someone finds a SQL injection vector to your db) cannot be mitigated by TDE, since the database will offer the decrypted data to any authenticated user. To mitigate such threats it means the data is encrypted with keys presented by the user (ie. only the user session can decryt the data becaus eonyl that session know the key password), but that knocks out the 'Transparent' aspect of all these encryption schemes. Having the user encrypt data with  it's own key password protects data from other users (other sessions), so it is stronger, but its *very* difficult to 'get right', and the user is always at risk at locking himself out of its own data by forgetting/loosing the key password.
3. Use integrated security and store connection string encrypted. Since encrypting the strings in Web.Config is trivial and well supported in ASP deployment and operation, just do it. Encrypting the string protects agains accidental compromise of the IIS/ASP host from a non-admin account. An admin account, or the account under which the ASP runs will always be able to read the encrypted connection string. Since the most likely attack vector will always be ASP compromise (ie. SQL injection and friends) the attacker will most likely be able to read the connection string even when encrypted, so there isn't that much benefit from it, but every little bit counts.